# What is the difference between data structures and collections in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I want to learn data structures and algorithms in java but I'm confused if collections are data structures or if there is something else . A brief explanation on data structures would help.

Thanks

Comment: Every collection is a data structure. Not every data structure is a collection.

Comment: When talking about the Java standard library, a _collection_ is a class that implements the `java.util.Collection` interface.

Comment: @jameslarge `Map`s are collections (by which I mean are part of the collections framework), but don't implement `Collection`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, Good point.

Answer (score 0):

Collections are data structures!  Data structures are just advanced ways to hold simple data (simple being integers, strings etc.)  data structures being things like Arrays, Collections.